# get city and country name from Google maps Platform's "Place Autocomplete" API call results in Flutter/Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-maps, format

I'm trying to obtain the city/town and country's name from the JSON response after calling  Google maps Platform's Place Autocomplete API, the original code is supposed to get a list of 5 "places" and display them on the screen for the user to pick from, I'm not sure how to extract the metadata from the JSON response to get the city and country names for each result and I don't know if that's possible, to be more specific, here's the complete code:

the code used to get the results of the JSON response:

```
Future<String?> placeAutoComplete(String query) async {
  Uri uri = Uri.https(
    "maps.googleapis.com",
    "maps/api/place/autocomplete/json",
    {
      "input": query,
      "key": apiKey,
    },
  );
  String? response = await NetworkUtility.fetchUrl(uri);

  return response;
}
```

AutocompletePredection:

```
class AutocompletePrediction {
  /// [description] contains the human-readable name for the returned result. For establishment results, this is usually
  /// the business name.
  final String? description;

  /// [structuredFormatting] provides pre-formatted text that can be shown in your autocomplete results
  final StructuredFormatting? structuredFormatting;

  /// [placeId] is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place. To retrieve information about the place,
  /// pass this identifier in the placeId field of a Places API request. For more information about place IDs.
  final String? placeId;

  /// [reference] contains reference.
  final String? reference;

  AutocompletePrediction({
    this.description,
    this.structuredFormatting,
    this.placeId,
    this.reference,
  });

  factory AutocompletePrediction.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AutocompletePrediction(
      description: json['description'] as String?,
      placeId: json['place_id'] as String?,
      reference: json['reference'] as String?,
      structuredFormatting: json['structured_formatting'] != null
          ? StructuredFormatting.fromJson(json['structured_formatting'])
          : null,
    );
  }
}

class StructuredFormatting {
  /// [mainText] contains the main text of a prediction, usually the name of the place.
  final String? mainText;

  /// [secondaryText] contains the secondary text of a prediction, usually the location of the place.
  final String? secondaryText;

  StructuredFormatting({this.mainText, this.secondaryText});

  factory StructuredFormatting.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return StructuredFormatting(
      mainText: json['main_text'] as String?,
      secondaryText: json['secondary_text'] as String?,
    );
  }
}
```

the code used to format the response:

```
class PlaceAutocompleteResponse {
  final String? status;
  final List<AutocompletePrediction>? predictions;

  PlaceAutocompleteResponse({this.status, this.predictions});

  factory PlaceAutocompleteResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PlaceAutocompleteResponse(
      status: json['status'] as String?,
      // ignore: prefer_null_aware_operators
      predictions: json['predictions'] != null
          ? json['predictions']
              .map<AutocompletePrediction>(
                  (json) => AutocompletePrediction.fromJson(json))
              .toList()
          : null,
    );
  }

  static PlaceAutocompleteResponse parseAutocompleteResult(
      String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<String, dynamic>();

    return PlaceAutocompleteResponse.fromJson(parsed);
  }
}
```

and finally, the code used to combine both of the above methods:

```
List<AutocompletePrediction> placePredictions = [];

void placeAutoCompleteCreateTrip(String query) async {
    final response = await placeAutoComplete(query);
    if (response != null) {
      PlaceAutocompleteResponse result =
          PlaceAutocompleteResponse.parseAutocompleteResult(response);
      if (result.predictions != null) {
        setState(() {
          placePredictions = result.predictions!;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

So, how can I get the city and country's name from each result in the response?

**AN IMPORTANT NOTE**
there's this weird thing in the "place autocomplete" API where if the user types the location in a non-English language like Arabic or Urdu, the country in the results appears first in opposite to English where the country appears last, is this intentional and can you still extract the country and city name from the result even if the language is not English?

I've tried formatting the code and following the instructions in this link from GCP "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete" but I was pretty confused and lost, I saw a similar answer for my question but it was in JS and I tried to replicate it but it didn't work.